# Angular Service and Controller common scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `AuthService` and want to use this service in some controllers.

I want to show or hide "log out" button in my front-end, depends on $scope.isLoggedIn.

My front-end code:

```
<md-button ng-if="isLoggedIn" class="md-button" ng-click="signOut()" aria-label="Logout">
    Logout
</md-button>
```

and my `signOut()` function:

```
$scope.signOut = function() {
    AuthenticationService.signOut().then(function() {
        $location.path('/');
    });
};
```

Authentication service contains functions: `signIn()`, `signOut()` and field `.isLoggedIn = true|false`.

And I want to update my variable in controller, `$scope.isLoggedIn` depends on AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn. But if I try this:

```
$scope.isLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn
```

it works OK, but only when I load site. So if user is logged in, variable `$scope.isLoggedIn` is `true` and if user isn't logged in variable `$scope.isLoggedIn` is `false`.

But if `AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn` change while application runs it doesn't change `$scope.isLoggedIn`.

Is it possible to keep this reference between service and controller? Or should I do this in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use also **$watch** in controller

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn}, function(newval, oldval){
   $scope.isLoggedIn = newval;
});
```

Comment: This will work, but it is a bad practice. You don't need to use $watch to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to do:

```
$scope.authService = AuthenticationService;
```

And in your view, access it by:

```
authService.isLoggedIn
```

The reason your current way isn't working is because you're setting a boolean initially, a value type, not a reference type like an object. So when isLoggedIn is updated, your scope variable doesn't know. When you set it to an object, in your case `AuthenticationService`, the reference to that object is maintained, and any updates are reflected in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make this into a function:

$scope.isLoggedIn

$scope.isLoggedIn = function(){ return AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn;}